# Server don't receive outputs from Client Socket

Tags: java, sockets, server

I am trying to test my Server to receive outputs from a client, works on Linux Terminal, but when I try to pass with another code, I am always receiving null values.

This is the method that I use to receive the input:

```
public String receiveString() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
    String input = null;
    try{
        input = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Inside:"+input);
        return input;
    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
        out.println("4");
        out.flush(); 
        client.close();
    } finally {

    }
    return input;
}
```

When I pass the output via Terminal, works fine, but when I pass via the code above, don't work, the receiveString is always showing Null.

```
public static void main(String[] args ) throws IOException {
    Socket client = null;
    try {
        client = new Socket("localhost", 12009);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
    out.println("Test");  
    out.flush();
    client.close();
}
```

All conections are working fine, just this part of the code is with problem...

Comment: What do you mean with "works on terminal"? Is that a telnet connection?

Comment: Are you using client.getInputStream() twice for reading? Once before you call receiveString ? Than reuse the first reader instead of creating a new one.